# Ramda : convert duplicate arrays to objects

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

converting the array of object with duplicates in it using ramda

```
    var testData = [
    {"id" : "001",
        "project" : "one",
        "projectstartDate" : "10/12/2018"
    },{"id" : "001",
        "project" : "two",
        "projectstartDate" : "10/14/2018"
    },{"id"  : "002",
        "project" : "one",
        "projectstartDate" : "10/12/2018"
    },{"id"  : "002",
        "project" : "two",
        "projectstartDate" : "10/14/2018"
    }
]
```

---

### need to get output as

```
{
"001" : {
    "one" : {
        "projectstartDate" : "10/12/2018"
    },
    "two" : {
        "projectstartDate" : "10/14/2018"
    }
},
"002" :{
    "one" : {
        "projectstartDate" : "10/12/2018"
    },
    "two" : {
        "projectstartDate" : "10/14/2018"
    }
}
```

---

creating object with id as key and removing duplicates

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Tried couple of functions from ramda pipe, filter, map, lens but not getting the desired output

Comment: Have a look at `R.groupBy(R.prop('id'))` and then see if you can modify the grouped values into the format you’re after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break this up into a few steps.

First, when you have a list of things that you want to group together by some feature, something like [`R.groupBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#groupBy) can be helpful. In this particular instance you want to group by the `id` property, so [`R.prop('id')`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#prop) can be used as the function given to `R.groupBy`.

```js
const testData = [
    {"id" : "001",
        "project" : "one",
        "projectstartDate" : "10/12/2018"
    },{"id" : "001",
        "project" : "two",
        "projectstartDate" : "10/14/2018"
    },{"id"  : "002",
        "project" : "one",
        "projectstartDate" : "10/12/2018"
    },{"id"  : "002",
        "project" : "two",
        "projectstartDate" : "10/14/2018"
    }
]

console.log(R.groupBy(R.prop('id'), testData))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Once you have these grouped, you want to convert a list in an object indexed by some value, which is often a good time to reach for [`R.indexBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#indexBy). Because we want to index each list associated with each of the grouped object's keys, we'll need to `R.map` over the object.

```js
const testData = {
  "001": [
    {
      "id": "001",
      "project": "one",
      "projectstartDate": "10/12/2018"
    },
    {
      "id": "001",
      "project": "two",
      "projectstartDate": "10/14/2018"
    }
  ],
  "002": [
    {
      "id": "002",
      "project": "one",
      "projectstartDate": "10/12/2018"
    },
    {
      "id": "002",
      "project": "two",
      "projectstartDate": "10/14/2018"
    }
  ]
}

console.log(
  R.map(R.indexBy(R.prop('project')), testData)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Then we have to clean up the left over properties left in the nested object. You've got a couple of options here, namely by either declaring which properties want to remove with [`R.omit`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#omit) or which properties you want to keep with [`R.pick`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pick).

```js
const testData = {
  "id" : "001",
  "project" : "one",
  "projectstartDate" : "10/12/2018"
}

console.log(
  R.pick(['projectstartDate'], testData)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Now all that's left is to join it all together with a pipeline using [`R.pipe`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipe) and [`R.map`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#map).

```js
const testData = [
    {"id" : "001",
        "project" : "one",
        "projectstartDate" : "10/12/2018"
    },{"id" : "001",
        "project" : "two",
        "projectstartDate" : "10/14/2018"
    },{"id"  : "002",
        "project" : "one",
        "projectstartDate" : "10/12/2018"
    },{"id"  : "002",
        "project" : "two",
        "projectstartDate" : "10/14/2018"
    }
]

const fn = R.pipe(
  R.groupBy(R.prop('id')),
  R.map(R.pipe(
      R.indexBy(R.prop('project')),
      R.map(R.pick(['projectstartDate']))
  ))
)

console.log(
  fn(testData)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```